# Luigi LocalTarget returns generic filename writing nc file

Tags: python, luigi

I am learning to use luigi and I would like to run this task I wrote which opens a file, modifies it, and re-saves the output:

```
class WindDirection(luigi.Task):
    uas_filepath = luigi.parameter.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("testing/wdir.nc")

    def run(self):
        # My task
        with nc.Dataset(self.uas_filepath, 'r') as uas_reader:
            wdir = NCdata.wind_dir_from_component(uas_reader)
        # Writing out the output
        wdir.write(self.output())
```

The task runs fine, but it is saving the file as `<luigi.local_target.LocalTarget object at 0x7f86ed64ee48>` in the same directory as the task instead of in the `testing` folder with the name `wdir.nc` (the file contents are as they should be).  Perhaps because of the naming issue, when I re-run the task it creates a new copy of the file instead of seeing that the ouptut file of this task has already been created.  I have tried both relative and absolute filepaths as input to the `LocalTarget` object.  The `.write` method that I am calling needs a string input that is a filepath, and I am wondering if that is causing issues.

What do I need to do so that the output file will be saved with the name I gave it?

In case it is important this is the command I am using to run the task:

```
PYTHONPATH='.' luigi --module basic_luigi WindDirection --uas-filepath /aboslute/path/to/my/file.nc --local-scheduler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
class WindDirection(luigi.Task):
    uas_filepath = luigi.parameter.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("testing/wdir.nc")

    def run(self):
        # My task
        with nc.Dataset(self.uas_filepath, 'r') as uas_reader:
            wdir = NCdata.wind_dir_from_component(uas_reader)
        # Writing out the output
        wdir.write(self.output().path)
```

When you call `self.output()` it will return `luigi.LocalTarget("testing/wdir.nc")` and not the path for the output. If you want the path you should call `self.output().path`